# My switch statement s not compiling

Tags: java, switch-statement

this is not compiling! I think I have done everything right. I fail to see the error here:

```
class A {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int x = 10;
        switch (X) {

            case 2:
                System.out.println("2");

            default:
                System.out.println("Def.");

            case 3:
                System.out.println("3");

            case 4:
                System.out.println("4");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `x` is not same as `X`. Java is case sensitive. Also show us the error

Comment: The `switch` statement is funny little thing, if you correct for your type (`x` not `X`), then it will print out `Def`, `3`, `4`, as the `switch` statement will run every case AFTER the first matching `case`, it allows you to do some really interesting things

Comment: There's a lot of problems here.  I'm not just talking about the typo or the placement of `default`.

Comment: default is not the case.

Comment: Indeed you should use the break; statement too.

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard That assumes you don't the fall through...

Comment: "*done everything right*". No, please.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: It doesn't compile because `X` is not same as `x`.

Comment: only X is the problem, put x - Also there is nothing like you have to put default at the end. you can place it anywhere. This is a fall through switch, I hope its not what you wanted - put break as well if reqiured

Answer (score 1):

try change the case of `x` and adding some break statements.

```
class A {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int x = 10;
    switch (x) {

        case 2:
            System.out.println("2");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("3");
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("4");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Def.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that putting `default` case in the end is a *good practice*, it is not mandatory to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

you have `x` in the declaration and `X` in the switch. Java is case-sensitive. 
`X` is different from `x`

`switch` looks at the `cases` and if a `case` satisfies the condition, it executes the `statements` following it until it finds a `break` or end of `switch` and it is mandatory, from the `programming and logical perspective` that you put `default` at the end of all the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your declared variable is called `x`, but in your switch statement, you are referencing `X`. So make sure to change that first. Second, you need to put `break;` statements at the end of each case-block.

```
switch (x) {
    case 4:
        // sysout
        break;
    case 3:
        // sysout
        break;
}
```

And, finally, you should also consider putting default at the end. However, thats just a convention making the code a bit easier to read.

Comment: The reason given for putting `default` at the end is nonsense. It can go anywhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got that wrong. It can indeed go everywhere.

Answer (score -2):

1. The variable you use for your `switch` isn't the same variable you've declared.  Fix the casing on `x`.
2. `default` *should* be the last option in your `switch` statement. It's good practice to do it that way, as it's conventionally the last branch that you want to execute.
3. You haven't placed a `break` in any of your `case` statements.  Simply put - if you do not place a `break` in your `case`, the subsequent `case` gets executed.  You need that abrupt return to help control what gets printed out.

   The above exists so that one could do fall-through cases; if you have two values that should go down the same branch, you could express them as thus:

   ```
   case 2:
   case 3:
       System.out.println("Number is prime and less than 5");
       break;
   ```

   Immediately after any of your case statements, place a `break` after it.  Otherwise your prints won't look right.